# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController search bar color and doesn't get changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, abpersonviewcontroller

I'm trying to change the color of the search bar orange and the bar tint color to white when a contact get selected.

No matter what I've been trying, nothings get changed and it's stuck like this (back button isn't white).

in AppDelegate:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationController class], nil] setBarTintColor:OrangeOfficialColor];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:OrangeOfficialColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

When popping the view:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *contactsPicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    contactsPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    contactsPicker.displayedProperties = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];

    [contactsPicker.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBarTintColor:OrangeOfficialColor];
    [contactsPicker.searchDisplayController.searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self presentViewController:contactsPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

1. View is OK:
   [image]
2. View isn't OK:
   [image]
3. View isn't OK:
   [image]

Comment: Did my answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once I started using Xcode 6 (iOS 8 SDK) and iOS 7 apps. This was my workaround fix:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```